# plotting a histogram using two vectors

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram of the total length of female and male fish as separate vectors. I've tried replicating other examples with my own data but it's just not working for me.

My vectors are different lengths so I've added NA to the male and tried to bind them.

```
#Make data frames
Female<-data.frame(1812, 1393, 915, 1863, 1263, 2140, 2125, 1195, 865, 1350, 1320, 1405, 1670, 1720, 1340, 1660, 1915, 1940, 1720, 1455, 1499, 2071, 1955, 2270, 1592, 2260, 2500, 1905, 874, 1684, 1842, 1702, 1873, 2234, 1876, 1787, 976, 1022, 1062, 1476, 1444, 1445, 2380, 1545, 1512, 1840, 2002, 1427, 1450, 1622, 1402, 1408, 1495, 1416, 1980, 1270, 2540, 1232, 1809)
Male<-data.frame(1470, 1596, 2332, 2049, 2103, 1555, 1760, 1123, 1059, 1601, 1370, 1805, 1295, 1313, 1405, 1870, 1765, 1515, 1292, 1730, 1647, 1931, 2255, 2130, 1735, 1460, 2188, 1121, 1121, 1940, 1722, 1530, 1530, 1553, 908, 1434, 1600, 1742, 1990, 1550, 1422, 2094, 1333, 1555, 1774, 1911, 1651, 1476, 1360, 1830, 1744, 1780, 790, 1046, 740, NA, NA, NA, NA)
#Combine data frames
Female$Sex<-'Female'
Male$Sex<-'Male'
#combine into new dataframe Sexes
Sexes<-rbind(Female$Sex, Male$Sex)
```

And now I'm stuck. I'm not entirely sure how I then need to incorporate this into the ggplot functions (this is my third day on R!) Ideally I want to create a Interleaved graph. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your first two lines. `data.frame` expects a vector which it will make into a column. You have given it a bunch of numbers which will all become their own column. Fix this by using the `c()` command and giving the column a name so it can be used later.

```
Female<-data.frame(mass = c(1812, 1393, 915, 1863, 1263, 2140, 2125, 1195, 865, 1350, 1320, 1405, 1670, 1720, 1340, 1660, 1915, 1940, 1720, 1455, 1499, 2071, 1955, 2270, 1592, 2260, 2500, 1905, 874, 1684, 1842, 1702, 1873, 2234, 1876, 1787, 976, 1022, 1062, 1476, 1444, 1445, 2380, 1545, 1512, 1840, 2002, 1427, 1450, 1622, 1402, 1408, 1495, 1416, 1980, 1270, 2540, 1232, 1809))
Male<-data.frame(mass = c(1470, 1596, 2332, 2049, 2103, 1555, 1760, 1123, 1059, 1601, 1370, 1805, 1295, 1313, 1405, 1870, 1765, 1515, 1292, 1730, 1647, 1931, 2255, 2130, 1735, 1460, 2188, 1121, 1121, 1940, 1722, 1530, 1530, 1553, 908, 1434, 1600, 1742, 1990, 1550, 1422, 2094, 1333, 1555, 1774, 1911, 1651, 1476, 1360, 1830, 1744, 1780, 790, 1046, 740, NA, NA, NA, NA))
#Combine data frames
Female$Sex<-'Female'
Male$Sex<-'Male'
```

Your command to `rbind` the data.frames just took the sex column not the whole data.frame. Fix this by removing the `$Sex`

```
#combine into new dataframe Sexes
Sexes<-rbind(Female, Male)
```

With `ggplot`, just give it the data and tell it how you want the aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Sexes, aes(x = mass, fill = Sex)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and although it has separated the two sexes looks nothing like a histogram. Just a load of thin lines and on density rather than frequency?

Comment: Change the binwidth argument if you want the histogram to have fatter bars. When I plot it, I get count not density.

Answer (score -1):

what you need is to make this a long table of data

```
Female<-c(1812, 1393, 915, 1863, 1263, 2140, 2125, 1195, 865, 1350, 1320, 1405, 1670, 1720, 1340, 1660, 1915, 1940, 1720, 1455, 1499, 2071, 1955, 2270, 1592, 2260, 2500, 1905, 874, 1684, 1842, 1702, 1873, 2234, 1876, 1787, 976, 1022, 1062, 1476, 1444, 1445, 2380, 1545, 1512, 1840, 2002, 1427, 1450, 1622, 1402, 1408, 1495, 1416, 1980, 1270, 2540, 1232, 1809)
        Male<-c(1470, 1596, 2332, 2049, 2103, 1555, 1760, 1123, 1059, 1601, 1370, 1805, 1295, 1313, 1405, 1870, 1765, 1515, 1292, 1730, 1647, 1931, 2255, 2130, 1735, 1460, 2188, 1121, 1121, 1940, 1722, 1530, 1530, 1553, 908, 1434, 1600, 1742, 1990, 1550, 1422, 2094, 1333, 1555, 1774, 1911, 1651, 1476, 1360, 1830, 1744, 1780, 790, 1046, 740, NA, NA, NA, NA)
        dat <- data.frame(value = c(Female, Male),
                          sex = c(rep("Female", length(Female)), 
                                      rep("Male", length(Male))))
```

This should get you to replicate the examples for ggplot2

Comment: This is more a comment rather an answer.

Comment: I've tried this and he keeps coming back with "Error: object 'female' not found"...